# Debug arrays from hook_cron?

Tags: 8, debugging, cron, log-messages

Does anybody know of the proper way to debug objects from within hook_cron? I'm trying to set up a task that periodically deletes backups from my private folder, but I can't properly debug arrays that I define in my module. I've tried both the object log and devel debug log modules, but neither of them are properly working for me at the moment, so I feel completely stuck on how to access the information I need.

I've tried running kint() directly, but I'm assuming that doesn't work because it's not running on a page load but in the middle of the cron task.

EDIT: Ended up solving this particular piece of the issue, but am having errors doing some of the deletion as addressed in [another issue](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/227768/delete-directory-from-private-folder-programatically).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using Ultimate Cron to run my specific cron task on demand, but used a method other than `kint()` to print my info. I ended up setting my info to a variable `$folders` and using the following to print the information in a text file: `file_put_contents("$private_path/folders.txt", print_r($folders, true))`

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try a module like [Ultimate Cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron) that allows you to run individual cron jobs, outside of `cron.php`. This will allow you to use `kint()` and see the output.

Comment: Great suggestion! Except that the individual cron job running functionality seems to be broken right now, at least on my end. I wonder if I've got another issue going on, here, that's affecting everything I'm trying...

Comment: Actually that may have been an alpha vs dev issue, because I switched over to the most recent dev version and the individual runs are working. Still no sign of my kint messages on screen, though. : /

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to log an array in dblog :

```
Drupal::logger('my_cron_task')->notice('<pre><code>' . print_r($myArray, TRUE) . '</code></pre>');
```

---

Other way is to debug with cli, so in your hook_cron() you print your array ...

```
print_r($myArray);
```

... then you launch your cron task from your cli with drush :

```
drush cron
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo` are displayed with `drush` on `hook_cron`.

A quick but not complete solution could be to echo flat array using this way. 
It could do the trick depending of your need.